# How to call function in model from form in zf 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

Im using zend framework 2. I want to call a function in model from zend form.

The situation is Im having a combo box & I need to bind data from database to fill its options and value.

This is my select tag in zend form

```
$this->add(array(

    'name' => 'ddlcountry',

    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',

    'options' => array(

        'label' => 'Country',

        'value_options' => (here I've to call function),

    ),

));
```

For this value option I want to call a function which is in model below is my function in model:

```
public function fetchcountry()
{

    $this->adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');

    $dbAdapterConfig = $this->adapter;       

    $dbAdapter = $dbAdapterConfig;        

    $driver = $dbAdapter->getDriver();

    $connection = $driver->getConnection();

    $result = $connection->execute("CALL sp_showcountry()");

    $statement = $result->getResource();

    $resultdata = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $resultdata;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get data from different model for select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022300/how-to-get-data-from-different-model-for-select)

Comment: I just updated my answer with the link to the correct question (which is also what i put up as duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

before you write such a Question, please check at least the first 10 Questions on this Page, as your Question has been asked SEVERAL Times lately ;)

Please refer to my answer provided here:

- [How to get data from different model for select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022300/how-to-get-data-from-different-model-for-select)

Or refer to my Blogpost, which covers your problem in detail

- [**Zend\Form\Element\Select and Database-Values**](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/)