# Create model instance in Form in ZF2 like ZF1?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In ZF1 it is possible to create an instance of a model and also access its properties from any  form class.`

```
class Application_Form_Drydepot extends Zend_Form
{

     $model = new Application_Model_DbTable_DrydepotModel();
     $List   = $model ->formationSelect();
     array_unshift($List, array('key'   => '', 'value' => '--Please Select--'));


    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
    $id->addFilter('Int')
            ->setDecorators($this->elementDecoration);


    $formation = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('formation_id');
    $formation->setLabel('Formation Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setAttrib('id', 'formation')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'required')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
            ->setMultiOptions($List)
            ->setDecorators($this->elementDecoration);
}
```

In here $model directly possible to call but use it easily but zf2 it is quite difficult. I am not successfull about to do it. In ZF2 how do I do it same operation.

Comment: See the answer provided by @Sam here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022300/how-to-get-data-from-different-model-for-select (it's also worth checking out the link to his blog post contained in the answer for alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

Another ways are like here : [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html)

### Programmatic Form Creation

ZF2 Coding close to ZF1

```
use Zend\Captcha;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

$captcha = new Element\Captcha('captcha');
$captcha
    ->setCaptcha(new Captcha\Dumb())
    ->setLabel('Please verify you are human');

$form = new Form('my-form');
$form->add($captcha);
```