# Dynamically set SELECT attribute in zend2

Tags: zend-framework2

What I am actually doing is, fetching a list of companies from the database and passing that to the form SELECT element.
So I created a Model file, which returns an array

```
//=== return an array of $ID => $name of companies to use in dropdown in reports form
public function getTotalResult($table, $type, $id) {
        $this->table = $table;
        $select = new Select();
        $spec = new  Where();
        $spec->equalTo('status', 1);
        if ($type == 'name') {
            $spec->equalTo('id', $id);
        }
        $select->from($this->table);

        $select->where($spec);
        $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
        //$resultSet->buffer();
        return $resultSet;

}
public function resultList($table){
    $results = $this->getTotalResult($table, '', '');
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $this->id[] = $result->id;
        $this->name[] = $result->name;
    }
    $result = array_combine($this->id, $this->name);
    return $result;

}
```

Then I tested this in my Controller, which returned exactly what I wanted:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use SpangelLogin\Model\Register;          // <-- Add this import
use SpangelLogin\Model\companyList;          // <-- Add this import
class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $registerTable;
protected $companyList;

 public function getcompanyList()
{
    if (!$this->companyList) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->companyList = $sm->get('SpangelLogin\Model\companyList');
    }
    return $this->companyList;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    //== get list of companies
    $company_table = 'rs_company';
    $sector_table = 'rs_sector';
    $companiesList = $this->getcompanyList()->getName($company_table, 2);

 }
}
```

So now I want this companiesList array passed in my form's Select Element. How can I achieve that. Here is my form in which I am using select.

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
```

use Zend\Form\Element;

class SectorReportForm extends Form
{

```
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    // we want to ignore the name passed
    parent::__construct('sectorreport');
    $companiesArray =  $this->companiesList();
    $sectorsArray =  $this->sectorsList();

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');

    $this->add(array(     
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',       
        'name' => 'company',
        'attributes' =>  array(
            'id' => 'company',  
            'multiple' => true,               
            'options' => $companiesArray,
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Company',
        ),
    ));  


    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Upload',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
            'class' => 'button violet right'
        ),
    ));
}


}
```

Comment: Please see my answer provided [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022300/how-to-get-data-from-different-model-for-select#answer-16022672). In addition to that the linked Blogpost by me may be of help to you, too. All in all please at least check the first page of Questions and answers. This exact question has been asked 4 times now on the first page.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Sam. And my apologies for repetition. But I couldn't get the right answer. And I already gone through your tutorial pages. They are helping, but in this case 1. No doctrine 2. No tablegateway as multiple table are being used.

Comment: Any possibility, I can get data into from by controller or Model directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Design-Perspective, the best approach would be to handle this via Dependency-Injection. That sneaky little buzzword that confuses people so much, but actually is nothing more but to forward data between objects :P

General Dependency-Injection for Forms can be seen looking at the following answer, as well as my Blog article

- [How to get data from different model for select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022300/how-to-get-data-from-different-model-for-select#answer-16022672)
- [**`Zend\Form\Element\Select` and Database-Values**](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/)

If you do not want to go this approach, you can handle this at the Controller level, too.

```
$form   = new My\Form();
$select = $form->get('selectCountries');

$model    = new My\Countries();
$listData = $model->getCountriesAsArray();

$select->setValueOptions($listData);
```

I still advise you to go the different approach ;) Keeps the controllers more clean, too, which is always a good thing. Separation of concern!

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks Sam. And for the right approach, yes for sure I will change my approach. As at the time lots of things are new  for me and the time crunche.

Comment: For Developers, there's never enough time to learn what we want, is there? :D Glad it worked.

Comment: Well I took your words (universal truth) seriously and read your blog again. Tried dbAdaptor approach for this, And yuppie.. IT WORKED. And solved my another proble regarding Zend Sql Queries. Thanks